# How to compile HTML file with SSI tags

Tags: html, nginx, ssi

I'm using Nginx SSI tags to include template files (header/footer/sidebar) in my website pages. However, I'm expected to deliver the HTML to the client and not actually run it on the browser.

The problem is: Every-time I want to export the site, I have to open each webpage, click 'save to' and replace the one with the SSI tags.

Is there a way to run nginx on these files and generate the HTML? Like `nginx -c index.html` or some other solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSI are meant to be run by a Nginx filter when serving pages, they are not a form of HTML shorthand (like SASS is for CSS).

Still, on Linux/MacOS (and Windows, if you download it) you can use `wget` to mirror you website. You will be requesting and getting all processed web pages that are (recursively) linked from the home page. Try with:

```
wget --mirror localhost:8080
```

or any other URL for your website.

Comment: Good. That does it :) I'll just add the -nH parameter to avoid creating a localhost folder